# Can Webbrowser Control handle "bad" HTML?

Tags: c#, html, .net, browser

I'm working with the Webbrowser control in C# and trying to access some HtmlElements in the document.
The problem is that the document Body only contains two out of five children. (http://www.target.com/cart/ref=nav_sc_rev_checkout). So I can't access specific elements in the body, although it renders fine in the UI.

I suspect that there is bad HTML in the Body so that the Document Tree is corrupt?

Is there a way to handle this, since it still renders nice..?

Thanks.

**Update**:
 The problem was that the DocumentCompleted event was triggered but the Doc was not fully parsed so that was why I only got 2 out of 5 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the WebBrowser is a wrapper round IE and it will handle bad HTML as good as it can.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply write the contents to a text file instead of a web browser control and make that into a HTML file. Then load it in your browser and inspect with the dev tool of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact the html code of this site have more than [200 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.target.com%2Fcart%2Fref%3Dnav_sc_rev_checkout&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&outline=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1) (mostly missing entities), you can try to load the code into an XmlDocument or XDocument inside your program and access the nodes you want via XPath.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to programmatically interact with HTML and more specifically bad HTML I would suggest you to take a look at [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

> This is an agile HTML parser that
>   builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually
>   don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is
>   a .NET code library that allows you to
>   parse "out of the web" HTML files. **The
>   parser is very tolerant with "real
>   world" malformed HTML.** The object
>   model is very similar to what proposes
>   System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or
>   streams).